# How can I remove the audio track of a media that I import into a Pitivi project?

Tags: video-editing, pitivi

Rather than changing the volume of the layer to zero, is there a way to delete the audio track from the layer altogether?

[image: Pitivi Layer]

The version of Pitivi I'm using is 0.95.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for adding the `/pitivi` tag. I think it would be better to have retained the `/video-editing` tag though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pitivi/+question/132343:

> Simple! Select your clip, click the Ungroup button in the timeline toolbar, select the video (not the audio), and delete it (or move it).

[image]

Just select the audio instead of the video.

Tested in Pitivi 0.96